# Calculating the Sum of values in ms-access

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have created a query to calculate the sum of all of the profit values in a table, I tried to output this to a textbox on the main form of my database and I just the error #NAME?.

Has anyone tried this before and are there any major things I am missing?

Comment: Need to see the SQL you used and you need to explain what you did to output it to a textbox. There is not enough information for us to even know where to begin.

Comment: I haven't used any, it's all through the interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would need to see some code/design details to understand why your text box gets  that `#Name` error.

Without those details, I'll just suggest you consider a `DSum()` expression, instead of a query, to load the text box.  And `DSum()` is kind of like a `SELECT` query, but returns only a single value instead of a result set.

```
DSum("YourNumericField", "YourTable")
```

Examine the DSum online help topic for more details.  You might find the optional *Criteria* parameter useful (like a `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` statement) if you ever want to sum only a subset of rows from your table.

```
DSum("YourNumericField", "YourTable", "account_status = 'ACTIVE'")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have create query to calculate the sum called "querySum". On the form property sheet, make sure **selection type** you change to FORM, go to **Data** and select "querySum" as **record source**.

And then, click text box, go to the property sheet and choice **Data > Control Source**. So you can choice column from query to the text box.

Otherwise, if you want to use VBA. You can do like this

```
DSum("NumericField", "YourTable")
```

Or with condition

```
DSum("NumericField", "YourTable", "type = 'Payment'")
```